# Put DIVS on one line then center

Tags: html, css, css-float, center

I have a form with 2 inputs and a submit button.

They are in different DIVS, so I'm using a left float to get them all in one line.

I have the whole thing contained in a larger DIV, and I'm using auto on the left and right margins to try and center the whole thing.

No matter what I do I can't get that form centered. It's making me crazy. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm just missing. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/T84hE/

Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
    #mc_bottom_signup{
         width:90%;  
         margin: 0 auto;

    }

    #mc_bottom_signup input[type="text"],
    #mc_bottom_signup input[type="email"] {
        margin-right: .25em;
        width:30%;
        float:left;  
    }

    #mc-embedded-subscribe {
        margin-top: 0;
        float:left;  
    }
```

Comment: Centering becomes very hard if parent div has a float property...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst this could be achieved with floats, I prefer using `inline-block` on children, then `text-align: center` on the parent.

### HTML (Removed placeholding `<div>`s & added indentation)

```
<div id="mc_bottom_signup">       
    <form id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" action="http://trinidadpena.us5.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=a99f40b5b94ce684ab690557e&amp;id=9d41329865" method="post" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" novalidate="" target="_blank">      
        <input id="mce-FNAME" class="required" name="FNAME" type="text" value="" placeholder="your    first name" /> 
        <input id="mce-EMAIL" class="required email" name="EMAIL" type="email" value="" placeholder="your email address" />
        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
            <input tabindex="-1" name="b_a99f40b5b94ce684ab690557e_9d41329865" type="text" value="" />
        </div>       
        <input id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" name="subscribe" type="submit" value="Yes, I want in!" />
    </form>
</div>
```

### CSS (Less specificity)

```
#mc_bottom_signup{
    width:90%;  
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#mc_bottom_signup input{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nHrSp/)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. This works too! And the code is much cleaner.

Comment: This for some strange reason, blew up when I tried it on the actual site. Everything was on it's own line.

Comment: If you would link to the site, I'd be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

## [--DEMO--](http://jsfiddle.net/T84hE/3/)

Use `text-align: center` , `display: inline-block` and `max-width:30%`

```
#mc_bottom_signup{
       width:90%;  
       margin: 0 auto;
       text-align:center;
    }
#mc_bottom_signup form div{
       max-width:30%;
       display: inline-block;
    }
#mc_bottom_signup input[type="text"],
#mc_bottom_signup input[type="email"] { 

    }

#mc-embedded-subscribe {

}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly in the demo, but on the site the button isn't on the same line. I can't figure out why.

Comment: What is the `<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"></div>` for? do you want to hide it or why are you using `left: -5000px;` if want to hide it just use `hidden` like this `<div hidden></div>` maybe that is the reason why it breaks on your website

Comment: To be quite honest, I'm not sure. I got that part of the code from the email service provider. I didn't want to mess with it too much and break it.

Answer (score -1):

`margin: 0 auto;` only works when the width of elements is known. I would set a fixed width then use media queries to set percentage widths as it looks like you are working on an email which won't support the other methods of centring content.

Comment: It doesn't work if parent div has float property set.

Comment: The container itself isn't floated so would work fine, the elements inside are floated.

Comment: Nope not an email. But thank for your reply, it's very appreciated!